# Laravel first()->count() return more than one

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm going to count total record of eloquent query using `count()`.

My table looks like this

| id | Code | Discount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | StarterResellerFree30Days | 100 |
| 2 | StarterResellerFree33Days | 100 |
| 3 | StarterResellerFree32Days | 100 |
| 4 | StarterResellerFree31Days | 100 |
| 5 | StarterResellerFree60Days | 10 |

Here is my code

```
 $eligible = Coupon::where('code', 'StarterResellerFree30Days')->first();
 echo $eligible->discount;
 echo "<br><br>";
 echo $eligible->count();
```

Here is the result

```
100

5
```

As you can see `$eligible->discount` return expected value, meaning `$eligible` contain only 1 record.

However, when I use `$eligible->count()`, it is returning `5` which is total records.

`$eligible->count()` supposed to return `1` because of `first()` and there is only one record matching the criteria.

Where am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `->get()` intead `->first()`

Comment: See Aleksandar Đokić's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made a mistake using `first()` method which is returning MODEL. You have to use `get()` method to return collection so you can do `count()` on collection retreived. When you use count on model it will return you number of models in database.

So you want to use

```
$eligable = App\Models\Coupon::where('code', 'StarterResellerFree30Days')->get();
```

as per on example below:

[image]